# Installing DHCP3 Server

Tags: kali-linux, dhcp-server

I am having trouble installing dhcp3-server on Kali Linux 2.0. I keep getting the following error `Depends: isc-dhcp-common (= 4.2.2.dfsg.1-5+deb70u6) but 4.3.1-6 is to be installed`

Does anyone know how to fix this? My Google-fu has turned up no results that can actually help me. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Run this, it just took me a lot of time sorting this out:

```
apt-get purge isc-dhcp-common && apt-get install isc-dhcp-common && apt-get install isc-dhcp-server
```

Then you might need to reset the network monitor:

```
service network-manager restart
```

And you're on Kali 2.0 so a special fix is needed that not many know about. Check the file 
`/etc/networkmanager/networkmanager.conf` and be sure this section is correct:

```
[ifupdown]
Managed=true
```

If it's set to false, it wont work.